# OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget (not an image size issue)

Tags: android, listview, memory, adapter

I know this error occurred many times on stackoverflow, but usually it was bitmap size problem. Mine is diffrent. I have a ListView with custom adapter. Here's my getView method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
    }
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_even_bg);
    } else {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_odd_bg);
    }
}
```

Now, when I have for ex. 100 cells in my listView and I scroll this list for some time, finally I always get an error OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - and in DDMS I can see that it happens while convertView.setBackgroundResource(...) is called. My drawables are 1x10px and repeated in Y-axis.

Comment: It is a pain... I'm having this issues too from time to time..

Answer (score 0):

I write a test application with 100 cells to verify your issue and found it works fine (scroll for many times), without OOM error.
There must be other memory leaks in your code.

Comment: I highly doubt that. Like I said DDMS says that exceed happened exactly in one of these two lines.

Comment: Do you view http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html? When OOM occurred,the DDMS says lines mostly isn't the root cause line caused the MEM leak. Can you publish your other code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't - but what I can say is that, when I change convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_odd_bg); to let's say convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREY); (and of course the same thing for even cell) problem doesn't occur.